# NgFor elements not rendering in Safari and iOS browsers (Angular)

Tags: html, arrays, angular, typescript, cross-browser

The browser is not rendering the `ngFor` elements properly, only a few appear. As you can see I have the required polyfills. Still not working correctly in Safari on desktop or iOS

See [live website](http://trumpfree.co)

Here is the code:

home.component.ts

```
this.feedservice.getFeedContent2(this.feedUrl)
.subscribe(
feed =>{
  if (this.notrumpcookie == 'yes'){
  this.field = feed.items.filter(feed=> feed.content.indexOf(substring) !== -1) 
  this.trumpContent = feed.items.filter(item=> this.field.indexOf(item) < 0) 
  this.feeds = this.trumpContent;
  }else if(this.sometrumpcookie == 'yes'){
    this.small = feed.items.filter(feed=> feed.title.indexOf(substring) !== -1) 
  this.trumpTitle = feed.items.filter(item=> this.small.indexOf(item) < 0)
  this.feeds = this.trumpTitle;
}else{
  this.feeds = feed.items;
}

},
 error => console.log(error));
}
```

home.component.html

```
 <app-feed-card2 *ngFor="let feed of feeds2 | slice:1:2" [feed]="feed" 
></app-feed-card2>
<h1> TOP STORIES </h1>
<div class="jumbotron">
<app-feed-card *ngFor="let feed of feeds" [feed]="feed" ></app-feed-card>
</div>
<div id="fries"></div>
<trump-slider></trump-slider>
```

index.html

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

<head>
<script src="https://cdn.polyfill.io/v2/polyfill.min.js?features=Intl.~locale.en"></script>
```

polyfill.ts

```
import 'core-js/es7/reflect';

import 'zone.js/dist/zone';
import 'zone.js/dist/long-stack-trace-zone';
import 'intl';
import 'intl/locale-data/jsonp/en';
```

view of home.component in safari: 
[image: safariview]

view of home.component in chrome: 
[image: viewchrome]

My angular version is the latest 5.1.1, I also have an open github [Issue](https://github.com/angular/angular/issues/21067)

Answer (score 2):

If anyone struggles with this in the future, the problem was a third party pipe that messed up the view.

Comment: Yea, for me it was Angular date pipe :/. On chrome works great, on Safari I had a problem debugging whole day! I still can not believe they did not "fix" it. Thanks for sharing info.